# What happens in Quern if you don't collect all the letters?

Tags: quern-undying-thoughts

In Quern - Undying Thoughts, near the end there's a puzzle which you can solve only if you collected all the letters throughout the game. So I wonder what happens if you didn't collect them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/512790/discussions/1/152390648085460545/), somebody posted the same question which was answered by a developer:

> What happens if you reach the library without reading/obtaining the letters?

> They magically appear in your backpack as you step into the library ;)